# why aren't finite fields of prime characteristic algebraically closed?

Tags: field-theory

How can this be proven?

I know that if a field has a prime characteristic, any element of the field, say $a$. will satisfy the following equation:

$ap = 0$, where p is the prime characteristic of the field.

I feel like the answer is right at the tip of my fingers but I'm just facing a road block for some reason.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: A few issues. In a field of characteristic $p$, $p=0$, so $ap\equiv 0$ Is just the zero polynomial.  Algebraically closed means that every polynomial has a root, not that every element is a root of a polynomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ are the elements of the finite field $F$, $(X-u_1) \cdots (X-u_n)+1$ does not have a root in $F$.